# accessing variables exported in a shell in the recepe file

Tags: yocto

I have a yocto recipe file.
However I want to set a value to the variable, by exporting a variable.

For example
I modified I added a variable in `oe-init-build-env`, (which calls 'svn_util')

```
export REPO_BRANCH_ROOT=${REPO_BRANCH_ROOT}
```

The REPO_BRANCH_ROOT variable is set by running a utility 'svn_util', by looking at by current branch.

Now in my recepie.bb file

```
SRC_URI = "\
    svn://${REPO_ROOT_NO_URI}/${REPO_BRANCH_ROOT}/sample  module=mymodule;protocol=protocol=http;rev=HEAD \
"
```

However `do_fetch: fails` as follows.

```
Fetcher failure for URL: 'svn://${REPO_ROOT_NO_URI}/${REPO_BRANCH_ROOT}/sample;module=mymodule;protocol=http;rev=HEAD'. Unable to fetch URL from any source.
```

How do I make .bb file to be aware of my current branch and repository uri? I do not want to hard code it in the .bb file, or local.conf file  Because if the .bb file is checked in to a different branch it should work correctly across all branch.

Or to rephrase the question, How a shell exported variable be accessed in the recipe file?

Comment: A possible solution consists in modifying the sourcing script, or writing your own, in order to take arguments from user and add these custom parameters in the `local.conf`. These values will be accessible from the recipe using both Shell and Python scripts.

Comment: That does not work for me , because I dont want to hard code, those varibale, But rtaher a script utility run through my directoctory, to find out SVN related info.

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer, from another post.
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#var-bb-BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE
In this case i have to add 
export BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE="$BB_ENV_EXTRAWHITE REPO_SVNREV REPO_ROOT_NO_URI REPO_BRANCH_ROOT"
In the oe-init-build-env